# Putting MySQL data from database into a variable

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm making a luck based website and I want to make sure they have enough spins on their account before they spin.

I did see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp but its not really what I'm looking for.

I have these rows with the names: id    username    email   password    spins.

I can deduct amounts from spins but I can't put the exact amount of their spins on a PHP variable to put in a $SESSION for a different page.

Here's how much I have so far.

```
$numSpin = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE spins";
```

Then put it in a $SESSION

```
$_SESSION['spinNum'] = $numSpin;
```

How would I go on to doing this? This does not work as is.

Comment: Ah, forgot. I'll just edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you are extremely new to coding so I'll try to help you out.

Here is the code you can use and I'll explain below.

```
<?php
session_start();
$host = 'localhost'; $db = 'db-name'; $user = 'db-user'; $pw = 'db-pwd';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8', $user, $pw);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $tbl_name = 'table-name-here';
    $un = $username;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=:un";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(':un', $un, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $totalRows = $query->rowCount();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Could not get the data: " . $e->getMessage());
}
$_SESSION['spinNum'] = $row['name-of-your-field-with-spin-numbers'];
?>
```

Then...

```
if($_SESSION['spinNum'] >= 1) {
    // allow them to do something
} else {
    echo "I'm sorry. It looks like you don't have any spins left. Please try again later.";
}
```

This code is written using pdo_mysql. You might want to read up on it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Line 2 starts your session

Lines 3-5 creates a connection to your database. Make sure to replace "db-name", "db-user" & "db-pwd" with your information.

On line 8 replace "table-name-here" with your database table name

On line 9 you can set "10" to whatever minimum number you want to make sure the account holder has.

On line 19 change "name-of-your-field-with-spin-numbers" to the actual name of the field in your database table that stores the account users available spins.

Now you can use `$_SESSION['spinNum']` on your other pages.

Don't forget to use `session_start();` at the top of any page where you want to use session variables.

Comment: Dude, you are the GOD! Most people don't actually write code for you here and explain indepth but you just DID! You're the first guy that is REALLY nice on stackoverflow. Most people just put "Too Broad", "Off Topic" and leave. Thanks again dude!

Comment: I'm just here to help. If I could tell you knew more about coding, I probably wouldn't have answered either. Everyone needs help when they're first starting. Some people seem to forget that AND seem to forget that at one point in their life they knew nothing about coding as well and needed a lot of help. Again, welcome to SO.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /srv/disk9/1921240/www/csgothrow.com/spin/checklogin.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /srv/disk9/1921240/www/csgothrow.com/spin/checklogin.php(4): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;dbn...', NULL, NULL) #1 {main} thrown in /srv/disk9/1921240/www/csgothrow.com/spin/checklogin.php on line 4

Comment: I'm getting this error when running the file. What would the problem be? It seems there is a problem with the PDO?

Comment: Where are you running this code? xampp or on a server?

Comment: Fixed it, now I'm getting this.

Comment: Could not get the data: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '1921240_spin.1921240_spin' doesn't exist

Comment: Seems like something is getting duplicated it? I re read the code and it didn't seem like anything changed.

Comment: It's telling you that the table "1921240_spin.1921240_spin" doesn't exist. What is the name of your table? Check this line to make sure it is correct `$tbl_name = 'table-name-here';`

Comment: YES!! I got it to FINALLY work. It seems I put in the database name instead of the table name. Thanks!

Comment: Shoot. can I make it so that it takes the variable in the login $username and use it to check which database entry the spins are on?

Comment: Basically, like this, $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

Comment: So I tried this on my own, I tried this. $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE spins >=:spins and username='$username'";

Comment: That might return a completely empty result if the user doesn't have enough spins. You probably should get the number of spins (even if it's too low) then use an if-else statement to allow or deny the spin.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't have enough spins?" Can I change the minimum? I made it 1 as of right now.

Comment: ok... you have it set to "1". I use my spin, now my spin count is zero. If your query asks for my username AND spins >=1 ... you will not find me because I have zero spins. The result of your query will be empty.

Comment: I have 7 spins as of now and if users have 0 spins, they can't come to the page and the script won't load at all. I have 7 spins but I can't seem em after the change.

Comment: On any other page that you want to use the session variable make sure you start off your code with `session_start();` THEN you can use something like `$spinNum = $_SESSION['spinNum']` anywhere else on the page

Comment: It was working before with your code in the question. I could see my spins. Thing is, my other members see my spins instead of their because the spins weren't connected to the username, it was connected to the first entry.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. Especially I changed lines 9, 10 & 12 and added a method for you to detect if they have the spins or not.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks a lot. It seems like all I had to do was move the $username variables in front of the code you gave me...